# Rails.env returning "Production" even though I'm running in Development Mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment

So, I've noticed that my Airbrake has been going crazy lately when I have an error doing local dev for my site... and I realized today that my site is running in Production mode by default.

Even when I run: `rails server -e development`,

It still runs in Production mode.

Recently updated the app to be Rails 3.2.* instead of 2.3.* - not sure if that could help.

Running Thin instead of WEBrick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
I went through and deleted all my initializer files, assuming that they might be an issue.
After adding them each one by one, I found the problem.

In one file, there was an if/else statement about Rails.env.

`if Rails.env = "production"`

Clearly, this is an assignment instead of a comparison!

It should instead be: `if Rails.env == "production"`

Feeling like a total noob, but hey! That's how we learn!

Thanks to @burninggramma for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)? If yes, you could just:

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec thin start`

or

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s`

Without bundler you could try: `thin start -e development`

**===== Update after some comments =====**

Maybe there is a configuration file which gets loaded when you start up thin. To debug this you could try creating a simple .yml file (lets say try.yml) with the content:
`environment: development`

Then try to start again with: `bundle exec thin start -C try.yaml`
To make sure that this config gets loaded you could add like: `port: 9292` to the .yml file, and see if the app starts on that port.

Comment: Thanks for the response @burninggramma!

Unfortunately, even with those specific commands, my rails app is running in production :/

Comment: Could you specify your enviorement?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean :/

If you mean by specifying it through those commands - then no, even when specifying `RAILS_ENV=development`, or `-e development`, it still runs in production

Comment: First of all are you using bundler? If yes what version? `bundle -v`. What version of ruby? `ruby -v` and `thin -v`

Comment: Well its all up to date, it should work. :/ last guess in my post.

Comment: ===== after try.yml implementation =====
added a yml file, port 9292. 

Thin boots up with that yml file on 9292, env still production :/

Comment: Ok, how do you know what environment you are running? I mean with wath method are u getting this info?

Comment: I can see the environment by outputting Rails.env in the view, or even when I boot up the console and check Rails.env, it's still Production